# как записать путь к файлу в переменной и открыть его на python?

Tags: python

```
import msvcrt
import os

yandex = 'путь к файлу'

key = msvcrt.getch()
if key == b'y':
    os.system(r, yandex)
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос. Не совсем понятно, как именно и зачем вы пытаетесь открыть файл - во внешней оболочке, или для работы с ним в вашей программе

Comment: Уточните всё-таки вы хотите, чтобы **выполнилась** какая-то программа с каким-то файлом или в каком смысле вы хотите "открыть файл".

Answer (score 0):

Это делается легко и без сторонних библиотек:

```
file = "path/to/my/file"
with open(file) as my_file:
    print(my_file.read())
```

Надеюсь это то что вы искали :)

Comment: спасибо, но это не работает

Comment: программа просто закрывается (я запуская программу в виде файла.py).

Comment: Ну так ты ее из редактора запускай. И проверь, что файл у тебя не пустой.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

file = "путь к файлу"

subprocess.Popen(file, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Вроде работает

Comment: А зачем нужно такое извращение? Чем вам `open` не угодил?

Comment: @Глеб, если человек хочет открыть файл в программе для его исполнения, то делать так. А если он хочет прочитать его, то open. Он не сказал, что ему нужно текстовик открывать, кстати.